# Under one package : compiler fails to read other class

Tags: java, compiler-errors, fsm

I have three java files in one package : 'Receiver'.

CMReceiverMutant.java

CMReceiverMutantContext.java

TestDriver.java

Here is my TestDriver.java

```
package Receiver;
public class TestDriver{

    public static void main (String[] args){
        TestCase1();
        // alternateTestCase1();
    }
    public static void TestCase1(){
        CMReceiverMutant obj = new CMReceiverMutant();
        obj.INT1SurvFlag();
        obj.Exitw0();
        System.out.println("Test case 1 reaches state :"+obj._fsm.getState().getName());
        if(obj._fsm.getState().getName().equals("CMReceiverMap.Final"))
            System.out.println("Test Case 1 passes!");
        else 
            System.out.println("Test Case 1 fails");
    }
}
```

I compiled TestDriver which depends on CMReceiverMutant.java. Eventhough I put them in the same directory. The compiler seems can't read CMReceiverMutant.java and it makes error :

TestDriver.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
                CMReceiverMutant obj = new CMReceiverMutant();
                ^
  symbol:   class CMReceiverMutant
  location: class TestDriver

I use cmd

javac -classpath Receiver\TestDriver.java

and I've tried
javac -classpath Receiver*.java

The errors are the same. Can you tell me whats the problem is?

Thank you

Comment: Did you compile those classes first?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes, I've compiled those classes before creating TestDriver.java

Answer (score 0):

please check "Source" packages in the "Java Build Path" sometimes if the package isn't registered there the compiler fails to load them.

Hopefully it worked for me.